# MySql query : don't wait for result

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous

I'd like to know if it's possible to execute a mysql query, and not wait for result.
Explanation : i have an insert query in a php page, which take some time, but it's not necessary for the page display to wait that it's complete. It's statistics, so even if it failed, it's not important.
I tried to use MYSQLI_ASYNC, but then, the very next request gets this error message :

```
Array
(
    [code] => 2014
    [message] => Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
)
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Run a cron job to update the statictics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let a MySQL query run asynchronously, but you can't send a second mysql query over the wire before handling the first.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.reap-async-query.php

Comment: Except that i don't mind the result, and it's an insert query, so no results to get, except for a true/false, which i really don't care about.
So, how to ignore or redirect this result ?
N.B. : I used mysqli_query, is this the right method ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you still need to do this. You need to tell mysql you are done with the current query before sending another.

Comment: Ok thanks. The way it's handled does not fit my need (which was "fire and forget'). I wanted to go faster, but it's 25% slower instead => rollback to synchronous version.

Comment: @MarvinLeRouge yea to do this right you need a semi-event loop and do connection pooling. The tools are all there for you to build it, but you gotta build it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like i found what i needed :

- this is a log table, with no relation to anything else => switch it to myisam => inserts much faster
- plus insert delayed for 0 wait time

Initial insert time : 90-120ms
New insert time : 1-2ms

Yessss !!!